# I'm making a WordPress CF7 Submit Button Text Changer

Tags: buttons, text

I trying to make it so I can change the text of CF7 submit buttons after users click on send buttons through a plugin. I've almost got everything working but I need a bit of help getting the data to save properly and show up after clicking the save button.

````
/*
Plugin Name: Glen CF7 Submit Button Text Changer
Description: Change the submit button text in Contact Form 7 after submission.
Version: 1.0
Author: Glen Rowell
*/

// Register the plugin's settings
function cf7_submit_button_changer_register_settings() {
    add_option('cf7_submit_button_changer_forms', array());

    register_setting('cf7_submit_button_changer_options_group', 'cf7_submit_button_changer_forms', 'cf7_submit_button_changer_validate_forms');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'cf7_submit_button_changer_register_settings');

// Add the plugin menu to the admin dashboard
function cf7_submit_button_changer_menu() {
    add_options_page('CF7 Submit Button Text Changer Settings', 'Glen CF7 Submit Button Text Changer', 'manage_options', 'cf7_submit_button_changer', 'cf7_submit_button_changer_options');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'cf7_submit_button_changer_menu');

// Display the plugin settings page
function cf7_submit_button_changer_options() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Contact Form 7 Submit Button Text Changer Settings</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields('cf7_submit_button_changer_options_group'); ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Form Settings:</th>
                    <td>
                        <div id="cf7_submit_button_changer_forms_container">
                            <?php
                            // Generate HTML for existing form settings
                            $forms = get_option('cf7_submit_button_changer_forms');
                            if ($forms) {
                                foreach ($forms as $form) {
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="cf7_submit_button_changer_form">
                                        <p>
                                            <label>Select Form:</label>
                                            <?php
                                            $all_forms = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'wpcf7_contact_form', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
                                            if ($all_forms) {
                                                echo '<select name="cf7_submit_button_changer_forms[][form_id]">';
                                                foreach ($all_forms as $f) {
                                                    $selected = ($form['form_id'] == $f->ID) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
                                                    echo '<option value="' . $f->ID . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $f->post_title . '</option>';
                                                }
                                                echo '</select>';
                                            } else {
                                                echo 'No forms found.';
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            <label>Submit Button Text:</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="cf7_submit_button_changer_forms[][message]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($form['message']); ?>" />
                                        </p>
                                        <button type="button" class="cf7_submit_button_changer_delete_form button">Delete</button>
                                        <hr>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            } else {
                                echo 'No form settings found.';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" id="cf7_submit_button_changer_add_form" class="button">Add New Form Setting</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // Add form setting
            $('#cf7_submit_button_changer_add_form').click(function() {
                var container = $('#cf7_submit_button_changer_forms_container');
                var template = '<div class="cf7_submit_button_changer_form">' +
                    '<p>' +
                    '<label>Select Form:</label>' +
                    '<?php
                        $all_forms = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'wpcf7_contact_form', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
                        if ($all_forms) {
                            echo '<select name="cf7_submit_button_changer_forms[][form_id]">';
                            foreach ($all_forms as $f) {
                                echo '<option value="' . $f->ID . '">' . $f->post_title . '</option>';
                            }
                            echo '</select>';
                        } else {
                            echo 'No forms found.';
                        }
                    ?>' +
                    '</p>' +
                    '<p>' +
                    '<label>Submit Button Text:</label>' +
                    '<input type="text" name="cf7_submit_button_changer_forms[][message]" />' +
                    '</p>' +
                    '<button type="button" class="cf7_submit_button_changer_delete_form button">Delete</button>' +
                    '<hr>' +
                    '</div>';
                container.append(template);
            });

            // Delete form setting
            $('#cf7_submit_button_changer_forms_container').on('click', '.cf7_submit_button_changer_delete_form', function() {
                $(this).closest('.cf7_submit_button_changer_form').remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Validate form settings
function cf7_submit_button_changer_validate_forms($input) {
    error_log('Validating form settings.'); // Debugging: Add this line
    $new_input = array();
    if (is_array($input)) {
        error_log('Input is an array.'); // Debugging: Add this line
        foreach ($input as $form) {
            $new_form = array();
            if (!empty($form['form_id']) && !empty($form['message'])) {
                error_log('Form ID and message are not empty.'); // Debugging: Add this line

                $new_form['form_id'] = intval($form['form_id']);
                $new_form['message'] = sanitize_text_field($form['message']);
                $new_input[] = $new_form;
            } else {
                error_log('Error: Empty form_id or message field.');
            }
        }
    } else {
        error_log('Error: Input is not an array.');
    }
    error_log('Validation complete.'); // Debugging: Add this line
    return $new_input;
}
// Enqueue JavaScript for changing CF7 submit button text
function cf7_submit_button_changer_script() {
    if (function_exists('is_plugin_active') && is_plugin_active('contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php')) {
        $forms = get_option('cf7_submit_button_changer_forms');
        if ($forms) {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    <?php foreach ($forms as $form): ?>
                        var formId<?php echo $form['form_id']; ?> = <?php echo json_encode($form['form_id']); ?>;
                        var message<?php echo $form['form_id']; ?> = <?php echo json_encode($form['message']); ?>;
                        $('body').on('submit', 'form.wpcf7-form[id="' + formId<?php echo $form['form_id']; ?> + '"]', function() {
                            var $submitButton = $(this).find('.wpcf7-submit');
                            $submitButton.val(message<?php echo $form['form_id']; ?>);
                        });
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                });
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'cf7_submit_button_changer_script');
?>```
````

Comment: Why is the data deleted when I click save?